# Concrete5 email not rendering correctly

Tags: email, html-email, concrete5, email-templates

Somehow when i send emails from cocrete5 cms its not rendering correctly in gmail.
It removes a complete style tag but the behaviour is not cinsistent.

This is my email template. I tried this hmtl in mailchimp, sendgrid, phalcon framework with swiftmailer and the output was okay everywhere in all platforms (gmail, safari, outlook.. etc).

```
<?php
$subject = 'New registration';

/*
 * HTML BODY START
 */
ob_start();

?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; width: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;" offset="0" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0">
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" role="presentation" style="position: relative; opacity: 1; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" style="background-color: #dbe5ea;padding-left: 8px;padding-right: 8px;padding-top: 32px;">
                <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" role="presentation" style="max-width: 800px;margin: 0 auto;">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;font-size: 16px;line-height: 24px;background-color: #ffffff;border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;padding-left: 16px;padding-right: 16px;padding-top: 24px;padding-bottom: 24px;">
                            <p style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;"><a href="https://grindfit.hu/" style="text-decoration: none;outline: none;color: #126de5;">
                            <img src="https://grindfit.hu/application/themes/grindfit/images/logo_black.png" width="250" alt="grindfit" style="max-width: 250px;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;vertical-align: middle;border: 0;line-height: 100%;height: auto;outline: none;text-decoration: none;"></a>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" style="background-color: #dbe5ea;padding-left: 8px;padding-right: 8px;">
                <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="max-width: 800px;margin: 0 auto;">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="background-color: #ebf5fa;padding-left: 24px;padding-right: 24px;padding-top: 64px;padding-bottom: 64px;">
                            <div style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;font-size: 19px;line-height: 28px;max-width: 584px;color: #82899a;text-align: center;">
                                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="text-align: center; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;font-size: 16px;line-height: 24px;border: 2px solid #3797dd;border-radius: 96px;padding-left: 16px;padding-right: 16px;padding-top: 16px;padding-bottom: 16px;">
                                            <img src="https://grindfit.hu/application/themes/grindfit/images/email/check.png" width="48" height="48" alt="" style="max-width: 48px;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;vertical-align: middle;border: 0;line-height: 100%;height: auto;outline: none;text-decoration: none;" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="font-size: 24px; line-height: 24px; height: 24px;">
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <h2 style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-weight: bold;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 4px;color: #242b3d;font-size: 30px;line-height: 39px;">
                                    Kérdőív feliratkozás
                                </h2>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" role="presentation">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" style="background-color: #dbe5ea;padding-left: 8px;padding-right: 8px;">
                <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" role="presentation" style="max-width: 800px;margin: 0 auto;">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="background-color: #ffffff;padding-left: 24px;padding-right: 24px;padding-top: 16px;padding-bottom: 16px;">
                            <div style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;font-size: 16px;line-height: 24px;max-width: 584px;color: #424651;text-align: center;">
                                <p style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 10px;">Az alábbi adatokkal kérdőívet töltöttek ki és feliratkoztak a hírlevélre.</p><br>
                                Név: <?php echo $name; ?> <br>
                                Telefonszám: <?php echo $telephone; ?> <br>
                                Üzenet: <?php echo $message; ?> <br>
                                Email: <?php echo $email; ?> <br>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" role="presentation">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" style="background-color: #dbe5ea;padding-left: 8px;padding-right: 8px;padding-bottom: 32px;">
                <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" role="presentation" style="max-width: 800px;margin: 0 auto;">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="background-color: rgb(31, 31, 31); border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px; padding: 32px 24px;">
                            <div style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; font-size: 14px; line-height: 21px; max-width: 584px; color: rgb(222, 222, 222);">
                                <p style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 16px;">
                                    <a href="https://grindfit.hu/" style="text-decoration: none; outline: none; color: rgb(222, 222, 222);">
                                        <img src="https://grindfit.hu/application/themes/grindfit/images/logo_white.png" width="200" height="76" alt="grindfit" style="max-width: 200px;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;vertical-align: middle;border: 0;line-height: 100%;height: auto;outline: none;text-decoration: none;">
                                    </a>
                                </p>
                                <p style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 16px;">
                                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/grindfithu/" style="text-decoration: none;outline: none;color: #ffffff;">
                                        <img src="https://grindfit.hu/application/themes/grindfit/images/email/facebook.png" width="36" height="36" alt="Facebook" style="max-width: 36px;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;vertical-align: middle;border: 0;line-height: 100%;height: auto;outline: none;text-decoration: none;">
                                    </a>
                                </p>
                                <p style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 16px;">©2020 grindfit.hu</p>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div style="font-size: 64px; line-height: 64px; height: 64px;">&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
$bodyHTML = ob_get_clean();
```

I upload a picture of my console when i check this email in gmail. I also marked where the style tag disappeared.
There was another case when the style tag was there but there was extra space in some of the attributes like max-width: 1 80 px;

[gmail console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYetu.jpg)

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

concrete5 doesn't touch the HTML template at all.

The problem is that Gmail removes most styles. I don't think there's much you can do about that.

Comment: I would not be so sure concrete5 doesn't touch the HTML. If it is working from other platforms, why not this one? Often the case with CMS's like WordPress, Concrete5 etc. is that they use a **web** editor, not an email editor, and the web editor will strip out anything that it think is not strictly valid. @user1874211 Can you try turning off all validation on your editor?

Comment: It's easy to be inspected what actually arrives in your inbox: simply save the raw email you received and inspect its html code